# PHP - MySQL INSERT query doesn't work with form action

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a form that takes input from the user and stores it in a MySQL database when the user submits the form.

```
print_r('<form action="" method="post">');
  /*
    form data, input tags, etc
  */
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table
            VALUES (...)";
    $insert_form = $conn->query($sql);
}
print_r('</form>');
```

Initially, the user stayed on the page when they submitted the form and everything worked fine. However, I updated the site to take the user to a new page after the form is submitted. The first line of the above code now looks like this:

```
print_r('<form action="next-page.php" method="post">');
```

I didn't think it was a significant change, but now whenever I try to Submit the form, I am taken to the next page without an insert into the database. When I remove the form action, the insert command works, and when I put it back in, it does not.

Any idea why this problem is occurring?

---

I have found a workaround using the php header function:

```
if ($insert_form)
    header('Location: next-page.php');
```

..but it feels a little sloppy. Any comments on this?

Comment: Thats how it should be... either redirect after the insert or redirect and add the insert in the next-page.php

Comment: the `action` attribute makes you go to its value, +ignoring all the line below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the if statement; Insert next line after the $insert_form.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table
            VALUES (...)";
    $insert_form = $conn->query($sql);

    header("location: next-page.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

`print_r` is mostly used to print out an `array`.If you wanna write your html inside a php `echo` will do your job easily.Normally a form submits the data to the current page if there isn't set or no `action`.If there is `action` it will take the form `value` to that next `php` file which you have set on your `action` and doesn't process anything within your current page.

```
echo'<form action="" method="post">';

/*
  form data, input tags, etc
*/
echo'</form>';

if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
 {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO table
        VALUES (...)";
  $insert_form = $conn->query($sql);
          header("location: next.php");

 }
```